# PHP Sorting a multi-dimensional array by field name

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have tried adapting this code to use to sort a multidimensional array on a named key/field. The field is an integer what I need to sort smallest to biggest.

```
function myCmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["days"], $b["days"]);
}

uasort($myArray, "myCmp");
```

This sorts the arrays as I need but in the wrong order. At the moment it sorts biggest to smallest, not using natural order. I need to sort smallest to biggest in natural order (eg 2 comes before 5, 12 and 24).

Answer (score 7):

[strnatcmp()](http://docs.php.net/strnatcmp) is your friend

e.g. (using a php 5.3 closure/[anonymous function](http://docs.php.net/functions.anonymous)):

```
<?php
$myArray = array( 'foo'=>array('days'=>2), 'bar'=>array('days'=>22), 'ham'=>array('days'=>5), 'egg'=>array('days'=>12) );
uasort($myArray, function($a, $b) { return strnatcmp($a["days"], $b["days"]); });

foreach($myArray as $k=>$v) {
  echo $k, '=>', $v['days'], "\n";
}
```

prints

```
foo=>2
ham=>5
egg=>12
bar=>22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just reverse the parameters of strcmp :

```
function myCmp($a, $b)
{
  return strcmp($b["days"], $a["days"]);
}

uasort($myArray, "myCmp");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to sort in natural order you should **not** be using `strcmp`, you can do:

```
function myCmp($a, $b)
{
  if ($a['days'] == $b['days']) return 0;
  return ($b['days'] > $a['days']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Here is a [working example](http://www.ideone.com/IRZUC).

Comment: If anyone is still watching, this does not return natural order. For the numbers 27, 2, 5 it returns 5, 27, 2